# Why is Sam specifically looking for 3 out of the same 4 Batman comic books?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-lost-boys

In ***The Lost Boys***, Sam says these words to Alan and Edgar about what comic book he wants:

> Sam: Actually, I'm looking for a Batman, Number 14.
>
> Edgar: That's a very serious book, man.
>
> Alan: Only five in existence.
>
> Sam: Four, actually. **I'm always looking out for the other three.**

Comment: Presumably he owns one, but wants to own every copy in existence?

Answer (score 4):

The literal translation of the conversation is meant to make it look like Sam has a book so rare that there are only 4 in existence.  By saying, "I'm always looking out for the other 3", it implies that he already owns one.

First of all, keep in mind that Sam is new to the area and looking to fit in.  If he makes it look like he owns a comic as "serious" as Batman #14, it would make him look cool.  And Edgar and Alan are in his peer age, so he's looking to gain some quick credibility.

Second of all, it's somewhat of a movie goof.  Batman #14 isn't really that rare, nor is it even as valuable as other early batman books (Batman #16 is even more valuable, in fact), and no where near as valuable as Batman #1 (which is currently valued at $120K for a mint copy).

Comment: No but it's fun to walk into a comic book shop and sees who gets the reference. Also it's not necessarily a good because as the other responders have said, more than likely it's a matter of personal value.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only four in existence, then they are very rare and valuable.  Owning all four would fill some personal goal - whether just having them all for himself or for the value he could get if he sold off some.

Answer (score 0):

Sam is saying he owns one of the four, already.

Thus, he only needs to keep an eye out for the other three.